# Express/NodeJS: all server errors silent in dev

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, nuxt.js, error-logging

For some time now, we no longer see any stack traces server-side in dev. Attempts to remedy this situation have included:

```
const server = express();

server.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.error('err', err);
    next(err);
    // res.status(500).send('Something broke!');
});
```

and

```
const errorHandler = require('errorhandler');
server.use(
    errorHandler({
        log(err, str, req) {
            console.log('log error', err);
            console.log('str', str);
            // console.log('req', req);
        },
    })
);
```

all to no avail.

For example:

```
server.get('/crash', (req, res, next) => {
  boom; // this line crashes
});
```

calling this endpoint does indeed crash, but no stack trace is visible in the server log.

We launch with:

```
npm run debug
```

which is configured like this in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "debug": "node --max-old-space-size=4096 --inspect node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt",
```

What are we doing wrong?

Comment: Are those handlers actually being called? Your question is missing clarity and debugging details.

Comment: As far as I can tell, no. Hence the "console.error" lines. I don't know what else to add.

Comment: Your app consists of more than just the few lines you're posting here. There's not enough context to help you out. You can take a look [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/debugging.html) on how you can debug an Express app.

Comment: OK, I added a few more details. Short of copying 16000 lines of code in server.js, I'm not sure what else to say here. What other information would be relevant, specifically?

Comment: Unless you can provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the issue is almost certainly something local. I'm not sure what exactly what you expect from SO other that providing some general tips on how to debug an Express app.